# Find overlap between intervals

Tags: java, jodatime

Suppose I have 2 joda-time `LocalDate` or 2 `DateTime` or an `Interval`. I want to find if an interval, ie. months july and august exists inside or overlap with that Interval. If so, I want to find the interval of overlapping. Is this possible with joda-time? If yes, how?

```
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2014-03-25");
        Period period = Period.months(6);
        DateTime start = date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
        DateTime end = date.plus(period).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
        Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
        // How do I find if this interval contains july and anugust?
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check whether the *whole* of July and August are inside the interval? Can't you just check that the start of the interval is at or before the start of July, and check that the end of the interval is at or after the start of September?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to find out if these intervals overlap, not only weather if one interval is inside another. I can do that the way you propose but I just wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Interval has an overlaps() method. If true, take the greatest of the two starts and the smallest of the two ends, and you have the overlapping interval.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I solved it using your suggestion. BTW Interval have also an overlap function which will return the overlapping interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got the desired result.

```
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
int startMonth = 7; int endMonth = 8;
DateTime month1 = start
        .withMonthOfYear(startMonth)
        .withDayOfMonth(1);
DateTime month2 = start
        .withMonthOfYear(endMonth + 1)
        .withDayOfMonth(1)
        .minusDays(1);
if (month1.compareTo(month2) > 0)
    month2.plusYears(1);
Interval season = new Interval(month1, month2);
if (season.overlaps(window)) {
    return  window.overlap(season);
}
```

The overlap and overlaps methods were really useful.